# "assign auto-incremented number for each group" What am I supposed to do here?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Recently I appeared for an Interview test and the question was as follows:

> 1. Create dataframe of the given list and assign auto-incremented number for each group.
>    lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A','A','B','D','E','F','F','Z']
>    e.g if A occures three times then 1st A will get 1 second will get 2 and third will get 3, same for B, 1st B will get 1 2nd will get 2 .....,C....etc

After a lot of thought, I came to a conclusion that we need to add another column that shows the number of times a given alphabet is occurring but I am unable to write code for it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.DataFrame` to create the DataFrame and `groupby`+`cumcount`+`add(1)` to create the index per group:

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A','A','B','D','E','F','F','Z']
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': lst})
df['idx'] = df.groupby('col').cumcount().add(1)
```

output:

```
>>> print(df)
   col  idx
0    A    1
1    B    1
2    C    1
3    A    2
4    A    3
5    B    2
6    D    1
7    E    1
8    F    1
9    F    2
10   Z    1
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for the answer. I was unable to solve it because I just didnt know about cumcount. Now I do thanks to you.